# Sending file upload status from react-dropzone component to parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm trying to send the the status of the uploaded file back to the parent component, using props and callbacks (as explained in [this](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17) tutorial).

My file upload is handled by the [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) component.

Here are my components:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            doneUploading: false,
        };
    }

    dataFromFileDrop = (fileData) => {
        this.setState({
            doneUploading: fileData.doneUploading,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <FileDrop dataFromFileFrop={this.dataFromFileDrop}/>
                { this.state.doneUploading ?  'Done uploading.' : 'Upload a video.' }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**FileDrop.js**

```
class FileDrop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { files: [] };
    }

    onDrop = (files) => {
        this.setState({
            files
        });

        // process file

        // send upload status to parent component
        const fileData = {
            doneUploading: true
        };

        this.props.dataFromFileDrop(fileData); // ERROR
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="FileDrop">
                <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>
                  Upload video!
                </Dropzone>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
```

When I run the app and drop a file into the dropzone, I get an error saying `this.props.dataFromFileDrop` is not a function. May I know where I'm making a mistake?

Is the error happening because I'm not passing `dataFromFileDrop` as a prop to the Dropzone component?

---

Adding this to the constructor in FileDrop didn't help:

```
this.props.dataFromFileDrop.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake in function name FileDrop - File**F**rop

```
//Replace
<FileDrop dataFromFileFrop={this.dataFromFileDrop}/>
//To 
<FileDrop dataFromFileDrop={this.dataFromFileDrop}/>
```

Comment: Oh my God, I don't know how I missed that! Thanks a ton. It works fine now!